# Need a way of storing a 4D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

For the simplicity of the questions let's imagine we were storing a :

```
int[][][][] values = new int[10][10][10][10];
```

I'm currently looking to generate tables of values which will be available for looking up later by the computer (not by a person). These values are basically scores for situations. So for example if we wanted to see the score where the first component is 2 the second is 3 the third is 7 and the fourth is 9 then we could go to [2][3][7][9] in the file instead of having to compute the value on the fly.

I understand the technical details of writing and reading to a file but I'm having a hard time getting my head around how to do this.

Let's say with a 2D array and I wanted to find the value of [X][Y] then I could just read and write to the row with value X and the column with value Y.

However, with a 3 or even 4 D array how can we store those values in a text file so that we don't have to generate the array everytime we run the program?

Comment: Serialize the array; but it won't be a text file.

Comment: @nbro - please humor me... how do you know its incredibly terrible? John did not provide a description of his problem.

Comment: @nbro What if you had a 3D array of sensors, each producing one sample of data per second? That data would be a 4D array. If you have nothing to contribute, please don't waste any of the comment-space.

Comment: It would be slightly easier to do it using a binary file rather than a text file. Using an `OutputStream` you could first use `writeInt()` to write the four dimensions (10, 10, 10, 10 in your first example), and then write all the numbers using four nested loops. You could then reverse the process when you read from the file using an `InputStream` and `readInt()`.

Comment: Despite the inappropriate rant, I have to agree to nbro to some extent: A 2D array may be OK. A 3D array is questionable. But 4D is at least highly dubious. If it was, for example, a 3D array of time series, then one would rather create an "Array3D" class with "TimeSeries" entries or so. One could even see *the question itself* as an indication that this is not the appropriate data structure here. But nevertheless, it may be answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to save this to a file would be using Serializable interface which is already implemented in primitive types (according to [this post](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=34789))

Example:

```
int[][][][] data = new int[10][10][10][10];

// Write object to a file
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("serializedArray.data")));
oos.writeObject(data);
oos.flush();
oos.close();

// Read an object from a file
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("serializedArray.data")));
Object obj = ois.readObject();
ois.close();

// Cast it back to an int array
data = (int[][][][])obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is an object oriented language based on Classes. IMHO you should work with it the way its made for.
Either make an Object with 4 fields or a quadratic diamond class:

```
class Quad<A, B, C, D>
```

I repeat again this is my honest opinion, mass downvotes INC.

Comment: how can you store a class on the harddrive instead of in temporary memory though?

Comment: serialize it, or even simpler parse it into a TxT:

Comment: The way its made for?

Comment: Yes. Java was made so you get favored by the classes. If you want to work on such low level as 4th dimensional primitive arrays you can always go for C